# Botón "Actualizar" y base de datos

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Actualmente me encuentra aprendiendo Python lo cual se me presentan muchas dudas al momento del desarrollo ,tengo problemas porque no tengo ni idea de como actualizar en la bases de datos sin utilizar el método `POST` o `GET`. Me encuentro desarrollando el *status* de una venta, por defecto el cliente tiene un *status* que es *Transito*:

```
admin_status_dict = {
    '1' : 'Tránsito', #Recibido Web
    '2' : 'En Proceso', #Verificacion de Datos
    '3' : 'Anulado',
    '8' : 'Facturado',  
}

status_dict = {
    '1' : 'Tránsito',
    '2' : 'En Proceso',
    '3' : 'Datos Confirmados',
    '4' : 'Tránsito',
    '5' : 'En Proceso',
    '6' : 'Despachado',
    '7' : 'Anulado',
    '8' : 'Despachado',
    '9' : 'Despachado',
    '10' : 'Facturado'
}

def admin_status(status):
    return admin_status_dict[status]  


def status(status):
    return status_dict[status]
```

**Mi View:**

```
class AdminOrders(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = "store.admin"
    raise_exception = True

    template_name = 'admin-orders.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AdminOrders, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = load_text({}, 'admin_feriados.json')
        context['days'] = eval(context['days'])
        Transaction.objects.set_all_totals()
        orders = Transaction.objects.all().order_by('created')
        context['orders'] = orders
        return context
```

**Mi Model:**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    objects = TransactionManager()

    q = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True) #Numero de contrato de la transacción con postheo.
    status = models.CharField('Estado de la transacción', max_length=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    observation = models.CharField('Observaciones', max_length=140, default='')
    sucursal = models.CharField('Sucursal', max_length=20, default='')
    pay_type = models.CharField('Tipo de Pago', max_length=20, default='')
    del_type = models.CharField('Tipo de Envío', max_length=20, default='')
    sug_date = models.CharField('Fecha sugerida', max_length=60, default=timezone.now)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=Decimal('0.0'))
```

**Mi Template:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como hacer para actualizar desde la base de datos el *status* del cliente, como podran ver quisiera que al darle al boton rojo de cada cliente pueda modificar desde el `status` que tiene que seria *Transito A Anulado*.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer seria hacer es algo parecido a.: `<a href="{% url 'app_name:cambiar_status" pk=id %}">` y luego en urls.py creas la url y le asignas el nombre cambiar_status o como quieras, y le agregas el parametro numerico `(?P<pk>[0-9]+)`, en tu vista creas algo parecido a:

```
def CambiarStatus(request, pk):
    cliente = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    if cliente.Transaction.status == 'anulado':
        cliente.Transaction.status = 'anulado'
    else:
        cliente.Transaction.status = 'transito'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('retornar:inicio'))
```

si no entendiste me dices, lo que hace es mandarlo a una pagina, cambia el estado y rapidamente te retorna a donde estabas o donde lo quieras dirigir, todo esto lo hace rapido, ni se nota

Comment: porque esta funcion `get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)` en si que hace esto?

Comment: Si viste el tutorial lo explican mejor, pero básicamente lo que hace es pedir en el modelo customer el objeto con el pk requerido si no existe retorna una página 404